# Understanding network options in Bitcoin Core GUI

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoincore-gui

IIUC first proxy option highlighted with blue is same as using `-proxy` in bitcoin.conf and second proxy option highlighted with blue is same as using `-onion` in bitcoin.conf

What is the use of checkboxes in the middle highlighted with red?

[image: bitcoin-core-proxy-options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These GUI features were introduced in [PR4587](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/4587), and they are available in Bitcoin Core since v0.12. The data in the red box on your screenshot are read-only, and they provide users with the actual proxy capabilities. Each checkbox has an appropriate descriptive tooltip. Also you could check out the `OptionsDialog::updateDefaultProxyNets()` function in the source code.